# Resolve service name in environment variable in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I'm really not sure what is going on and what is problem, when I pass service name in environment variable in YAML file, that service name is still string, it's not being resolved in real ip address.

Does it should work by automatically inside kubernetes, or I need to do some more config in order that service is resolved.

Example like this, new deployment:

```
env:
   -name: MYSQL-SERVICE
    value: my-service-name-which-should-be-resolved (also deployed on kubernetes as service)
```

thanks a lot for any advice!

Comment: Do 'kubectl describe pod <pod>' or check the dashboard to see what value is passed into the pod. Likewise check the service name with 'kubectl get service'. If they match and are in same namespace it should work. Would help if you can share as much output and descriptors you can.

Comment: _that service name is still string, it's not being resolved in real ip address_ why in the world would you expect an environment variable to be converted from a DNS name into an IP? Are you perhaps thinking of `$MYSQL_SERVICE_HOST`, which would be injected automatically by `kubelet` for a `mysql` `Service` in the `Pod`'s namespace?

Comment: @RyanDawson Value which is passed into the Pod is "my-service-name", string not any IP of service. They match and they are in same namespace. So, maybe my Service which needs this Service from EnvVar. should handle that like full dns name, not like IP addres, because i'm expect IP address.

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel So, i'm not sure, some guys says Kubernetes will replace service name with IP of that service, so this is wrong? MYSQL is just example, nothing related. I can go with passing string name of service which i want and then  i that application which use that service I should use service like full dns name not like iP? Thanks

Comment: Yes you can just use the service name of the msql service as a host name. An example is https://blog.learnk8s.io/connect-service-kubernetes-7cb346cf2f64

Answer (score 0):

@MatthewLDaniel and @RyanDawson are right. In this case, environment variable could not be converted into IP address, and you should use Service name.

More details you can find in [DNS for Services and Pods](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/) and [Services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/).